# Flaskserver running but not routing?

Tags: python, user-interface, flask

Hey I ran the flask basic code as follows -

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Then I ran the server as stated in docs and it ran fine. 
But now when i got 127.0.0.1:5000/ nothing happens. The browser keeps circling as if refreshing the page but doesn't route.

Its my first python/flask code so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

EDIT- By docs I mean quickstart documentation of flask. I know its fine cz i get this - 
 Serving Flask app "hello"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: "Then I ran the server as stated in docs and it ran fine" what docs, specifically? And how did you confirm that it ran fine?

Comment: @raganjosh Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added `app.run()` to the same code and executed which is working fine. Can you try it?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using this [Quickstart - A Minimal Application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).

That said let's make some points clear:

When you said

> I know its fine cz i get this - Serving Flask app "hello"

You do not use the extension .py, which can cause some problems if you have another file with the same name in this directory. So make sure your FLASK_APP variable is correct.

This should work for you, but if the problem persist enable the Debug Mode adding
`FLASK_ENV=development` to your environment variable and see which error appears for you.

Hoping this solve your problem.